# Eevee Depth of Field causes weird pixels at the edge

Tags: eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

I am rendering an image with the Depth of Field setting on the camera. This causes the edge pixels on the right-hand side to display an unwanted solid color. Here is an image from the viewport preview and the resulting render:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue properly? (Other than trying to paint over it in post production.)

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you test this with Filmic color management

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am already using Filmic. other color management options have also not changed the outcome

Comment: Hello :). This shouldn't be happening, and I can't reproduce the issue. Consider [sharing your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: oh, i have to apologize, i actually mistakenly said I was using Cycles while it was Eevee. unfortunately i dont feel comfortable sharing the file

Comment: I think that this is a common limitation of any blur-like procedure related to the kernel is being used for the convolution. I didnt try it in order to see if this is a unique case, but I guess this one looks more like a bug.